# Container borderRadius covered by sub view, Is this a bug?

Tags: react-native

the screenshot:

[image]

In the root view, I set borderRadius is 17, it display well on right, but on the left, the border radius covered by green sub view and yellow sub view, is this a bug?

Comment: I setting overflow: 'hidden' on the root view's style. And it works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android overflow on parent elements won't clip children. It is a known issue:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/known-issues.html

Comment: Is this still true as of July 2017? (react-native v0.48.3)

Answer (score 38):

Set `{overflow: 'hidden'}` on the root view's style.

Comment: Amazing, Great answer

Comment: If your root view has a shadow, this breaks it.

Comment: Create another parent container for the shadow styles so that `overflow: 'hidden'` doesn't affect the shadow.